# Passar valor do PHP para o Form SimpleModal via GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estou usando o [SimpleModal Contact Form de Eric Martin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/), mas estou com uma dificuldade em passar uma variável para o `form` via GET.

Eu queria que, no `index.php`, eu pudesse enviar a variável `$palestra_titulo`, e que esta fosse usada no Form no campo "Subject", já aparecendo preenchido e sendo usado para enviar por e-mail.

No index.php, o método GET seria passado através de uma imagem. Seria algo como `<a href='data/contact.php?article_id=<?php $id ?>' class="contact"><img src="x.gif"/></a>`.

No contact.js, tenho uma função ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data/contact.php',
      data: $('#contact-container form').serialize() + '&action=send&',
      type: 'post',
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function (data) {
          $('#contact-container .contact-loading').fadeOut(200, function () {
            $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Obrigado!');
            msg.html(data).fadeIn(200);
          });
       },
       error: contact.error
     });
```

E no contact.php, o trecho que exibe o campo é:

```
    $action = isset($_POST["action"]) ? $_POST["action"] : "";
    if (empty($action)) {
  // Send back the contact form HTML
  $output = "<div style='display:none'>
  <div class='contact-top'></div>
  <div class='contact-content'>
    <h1 class='contact-title'>Inscreva-se Aqui</h1>
    <div class='contact-loading' style='display:none'></div>
    <div class='contact-message' style='display:none'></div>
    <form action='#' style='display:none'>
       <label for='contact-name'>*Nome:</label>
       <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' />
       <label for='contact-email'>*E-mail:</label>
       <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='email' tabindex='1002' />";

if ($extra["form_subject"]) {
    $output .= "
    <label for='contact-subject'>Palestra:</label>
    <input type='text' id='contact-subject' class='contact-input' name='subject' value='' tabindex='1003' />";
}
```

O value que deveria exibir o valor da variável $palestra_titulo está na última linha.

Que modificações no `contact.js` e `contact.php` devo fazer para isso?

Comment: Não te serve imprimir a variável no atributo `value` do `input`? Algo como: `<input value='<?php echo $palestra_titulo ?>'>...`

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Só para lhe ajudar a se acostumar com nossa filosofia, que é diferente de um fórum, dê uma olhada em pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior, especialmente o 3o. item. Se ainda não leu, seria bom dar uma olhada em [about], você ganha uma medalha. Você pode usar o [edit] para deixar sua pergunta com o jeito de uma pergunta direta e limpa. Aos poucos você vai acostumando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dada a falta de informações importantes, como por exemplo o seu HTML atual, bem como uma descrição um pouco mais detalhada sobre o que exatamente está tentando fazer, vou assumir os dois melhores cenários que posso construir com o que tenho em mãos.

### Cenário #1

O termo `paletras_titulo` **já está** presente na URL da página que abrirá o modal. Nesse caso basta você sequir a sugestão comentada do amigo Anddrey e ecoar o valor n=dentro do atributo *value* do *input* desejado.

No entanto, ligeiramente diferente do que ele sugeriu, ao invés de ecoar uma variável qualquer, você puxará tal informação do superglobal `$_GET`:

```
<input value='<?php echo ( isset( $_GET['palestra_titulo'] ) ? $_GET['palestra_titulo'] : '' ) ?>' />
```

### Cenário #2

O termo `paletras_titulo` **não está** presente na URL da página que abrirá o modal.

Nesse caso você tem pelo menos duas opções:

1) Preencher, com JavaScript, o atributo value do elemento HTML em questão mesclando o JS com alguma variável PHP. Algo assim:

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready( function() {

        $( "#title" ).val( "{$paletra_titulo}" );
    });

</script>';

?>

<!-- Mais HTML -->

<form id="modal">
    <input id="title" name="title" value="" />
</form>
```

Pessoalmente eu acho isso extremamente danoso a manutenibilidade da Aplicação.

2) Se valer dos callbacks *onOpen()* ou *onShow()* do plugin e requisitar o título da palaestra por AJAX. Algo assim:

```
$("#element-id").modal(

    {
        onOpen: function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "sua_url.php",
                data: { id: 123 },
                success: function( response ) {

                    $( '#title' ).val( response );
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Observe que **123** não deve ser usado. Este deve ser substituído pelo real valor do ID da palestra que muito provavelmente está presente na URL, também em forma de querystring, haja vista este ser o modo mais básico de transitar dados num CRUD.

Atente também para que dependendo do quê você tiver como output do URL aqui nomeado *sua_url.php*, o **response** dentro de *jQuery.val()* pode mudar.

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão ou correção de sintaxe, por favor, à vontade.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas. Conforme a sugestão, editei a pergunta, acrescentando mais informações.